# Visual Studio Diagnostic Tools show only "[Native]" under CPU Usage - "Source information is not available"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I created a Visual Studio Solution with 2 c++ projects. I am compiling the first project as a **static library** and use that library in the other project. The other project is a **Qt-Application (.exe)** that uses classes and functions from the static library. When I run the Debugx64 configuration, the **Diagnostic Tools** window should allow me to inspect the **CPU Usage** and view a list of functions and their CPU loads. However, under CPU Usage all I can see right now, is a category called *[Native]* that uses 99.8% of the CPU. I cannot get any more details about functions called and their CPU usage. Within the CPU Usage window there is also a message saying **"Source information is not available"**.
Does anyone know how to resolve this to see the actual list of called functions instead of just *[Native]*? Is this an issue related to missing symbols?

I am using VS2019 (VS2022 same problem).

I have tried so far:

- Project settings of the static library > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Set *Debug Information Format* to *Program Database (/Zi)*
- Options > Debugging > General > disabled "Require source files to exactly match the original version"
- Options > Debugging > Symbols > Empty Symbol Cache / Load all symbols
- Options > Debugging > Symbols > Added *path/to/staticlibrary.pdb* to the list of Symbol file locations

I appreciate any further ideas, I am really stuck with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to uncheck the check box in "Diagnostics Tools / CPU Usage / Filter / Hide Native Code", then press "Apply" button.